# Directory not found in unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

When calling unit test in another directory, it does not import the data I needed.

Directory goes like this:

```
GenerateValues
--app folder
----process_data.py
----input_files.py
----model_data folder
------data.json
----block_tests
------test_1.py
------test_2.py
--test.py
```

I need to call unittest in test.py.

In the unit tests under block_tests, I have been calling process_data for assertion. process_data.py calls data.json and use it to do the processing.

input_files.py

```
folder = "model_data"
data1 = f"{folder}/data.json"
```

process_data.py

```
class ProcessData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.load_data() 
    def load_data(self):
        fn = model.data1
        #loads data then to be used in process
```

test_1.py

```
class TestData(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.data_service = ProcessData()
```

test.py

```
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
test_runner = unittest.runner.TextTestRunner()
tests = loader.discover("block_tests")
test_runner.run(tests)
```

Error is this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'model_data/data.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pathlib provides some great helpers that will make this a bit easier for you. If you change `input_files.py` to be:

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path(__file__).parent / "model_data"
data1 = folder / "data.json"
```

This uses the `__file__` attribute to get the path of `input_files.py`, then uses `pathlib.Path` to figure out the directory it lives in(`.parent`). This can then be used to point to the `model_data` folder, and then the specific json you need to load.

Caveat: I may have the exact paths wrong here because I am reading your directory tree rather than looking at a real one. You may need to tweak the exact path wrangling!